# settings on application.rb file doesn't take account?

Tags: ruby, ruby-on-rails-4

I'm new in ruby on rails, i have add in application.rb / production.rb file settings and new settings seems not be taken account. How I can do if I want my new settings updated.
Thanks

Comment: What did you change? Did you restart the server after changing the config?

Answer (score 0):

have you restart your rails server after the changes?  `Ctrl C` and `rails s`